# what do you actually buy when buying domain names

Tags: dns, internet, domain-name

I've come up with an odd question. What do I actually buy, when I buy a domain name. I mean, domain names are just human readable IP addresses and the IP addresses must be provided by the buyer. Do I pay for storing a domain name and IP address on a DNS server? If so, why isn't everybody in this business? Seems like an easy money.

Comment: You do not actually buy a domain name, its more of a lease. As long as you make the lease payments it is yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be accredited to become a TLD registrar. TLDs include `.com` etc.

There are a number of complex and expensive processes - this is why it's not so easy to just become a registrar!

Source: https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/accreditation-2012-02-25-en

Companies such as 123-Reg (UK) are accredited and this is why they can sell domain names of `.co.uk`, `.com` etc. - they've been through the process - hence why they are such big companies and not just an SMB.

Comment: thank you! Based on the link, ICANN organization has the power to determine who can link IPs with domain names. Is there a reason they are in charge? Did they "create" the internet? It all looks like a mob business to uneducated :D

Comment: ICANN Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICANN

Comment: @brumbrum: In the good old days I registered a .com domain (for free) by sending email to the US army (DDN-NIC) giving the ip-addresses of my DNS servers. Eventually the US army decided that they had better things to do and by a complicated process the registry business was privatised.